# What's the geometrical meaning of $f'''(x)$?

Tags: derivatives

It's well-known that $f'(x),f''(x)$ determine the monotonicity and the concavity of $f(x)$ respectively. Besides, we can **see** $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ from the graph of $f(x)$.

But how about $f'''(x)$ and other higher orderd derivative? What's its geometrical meaning on the graph of $f(x)$? Or, limited by our human-being's perception, we can't **see** high-orderd derivative?

Comment: The view I think is most "easy" to understand is if we are talking about forces, the third derivative of $f(t)$(place(time)) is the rate of change of the force(up to constant)

Comment: See [Third derivative: Applications in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_derivative#Applications_in_geometry) : "In differential geometry, the [torsion of a curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve) is computed using third derivatives".

Comment: @mengdie1982 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Usually we don't give a specific geometrical meaning to $f'''(x)$ with reference to $f(x)$ but we can observe that $$f'''(x)=(f''(x))'=(f'(x))''$$

and therefore $f'''(x)$ represents

- the slope of $f''(x)$
- the convexity/concavity of $f'(x)$

With reference to $f(x)$, we can be interested in the higher order derivatives to determine the nature of critical points.

Notably, when derivatives exist if $f'(x_0)=0$ and $\exists k \geq 2$ s.t. $f^k(x_0) \neq 0$ then

- when **k is even** we have a max/min in $x_0$ (depending on the sign)
- when **k is odd** we have an inflection point in $x_0$

Comment: I can agree with you！But what I want to know is that where $f'''(x)$ is on the graph of $f(x)$ itself...

Comment: Otherwise, you can always say that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the slope of $f^{(n-1)}(x)$. That seems too trivial.

Comment: @mengdie1982 I'm sorry that it is trivial but there is no other general meaning for that.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)$ represents position at time $t$, then the third derivative $f'''(t)$ is sometimes called *jerk* and represents change in acceleration at time $t$. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) on Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: I know that physical concept. You can feel the velocity when you are driving, and the acceleration when you are stepping on the gas. But how you feel the so-called JERK?